# How can I update progress bar extension?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have an extension that loads a progress bar inside the nav bar.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .bar)
        self.view.addSubview(progressView)
        let navBar = self.navigationBar

        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[navBar]-0-[progressView]", options: .directionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["progressView" : progressView, "navBar" : navBar]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[progressView]|", options: .directionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["progressView" : progressView]))

        progressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)
        
    }
}
```

In my UIViewController class, how can I update the progress bar using `progressView.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)`? I want to increase the value to 0.1 from within a @IBAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't use stored properties in extensions you have to add a way to identify the progress view for example by assigning a tag

```
...
let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .bar)
progressView.tag = 1024
self.view.addSubview(progressView)
...
```

Then you can create a method which updates the progress view

```
func updateProgressView(value: Float) {
    let progressView = view.subviews.first{$0.tag == 1024} as! UIProgressView
    progressView.setProgress(value, animated: true)
}
```

or

```
func increaseProgress() {
    let progressView = view.subviews.first{$0.tag == 1024} as! UIProgressView
    progressView.progress += 0.1
}
```